# Check if element has animation-name attached by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to make something like this.

CSS library Animate.css

```
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.animate__fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
.animate__animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="animatedScroll animate__animated animate__fadeInUp" style="animation-delay: 0.3s;"><p>111</p></div>
<div class="animatedScroll"><p>222</p></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    var element = $('.animatedScroll');
    $.each(element, function(i){
        let ele = $(this);
        var hasAnimation = false;
        var name = '';

        $(this).on('animationstart', function(e){
            // If the element has an animation and it's start running
            hasAnimation = true;
            name = e.originalEvent.animationName;
        });

        if ( hasAnimation === true ) {
            console.log('animation name is : ' + name);
        }
        else {
            console.log('no animation');
        }
    });
})
```

I'm expecting the console log is `animation name is : fadeInUp` and `no animation`.

But the result is `no animation` for both element.

As far as i know it's because event `animationstart` fire off late.

Is there any other way to achive same goal?
And can this be solve with deferred object?

Comment: Please post your relevant code for animation, we see no animation at all.  And please elaborate more what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @ikiK sr. I'm already edit my question. Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

I tidied up ypur code a little bit. Your `console.log()` for the animation was executed immediately after you define the action for the "animationstart" event. That is much before the actual animation starts. Therefore the result was always: "no animation". Following @Ikik's advice I now introduced a "reporting function" that gives you a report about the current state of the system. I trigger the report once before the animation and once after (inside the event function).

The other thing I changed is that I associated the animation information directly with the DOM element by using its `data` attribute. These attributes can be accessed from JavaScript through the `.dataset` property.

```js
var as=$('.animatedScroll');
as.each(function(i,ele){
  ele.hasAnimation=false;
  ele.name='';
  $(ele).on('animationstart', function(e){
    // If the element has an animation and it's start running
    ele.dataset.hasAnimation=true;
    ele.dataset.name = e.originalEvent.animationName;
    animationReport(as); // report after animation
  });
});

animationReport(as); // report before animation
  
function animationReport(sel){ // reports the most recent animation for each
  sel.each(function(i,ele){    // DOM element found in the given jQuery object sel
    console.log(ele.textContent+' has '+(ele.dataset.name||'no animation'))
  })
}
$('button').click(function(){animationReport(as)});
```

```css
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.animate__fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
.animate__animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="animatedScroll animate__animated animate__fadeInUp" style="animation-delay: 0.3s;"><p>111</p></div>
<div class="animatedScroll"><p>222</p></div>
<button> report again </button>
```

Comment: I made this too, but I think he also wants for other div with no animation console.lo no animation

Comment: This worked.
But when i remove the "animation-delay" from first div it's return "no animation" for all elements.
how can i fix this.

Comment: @BaoPham You have two reports, only one is failing (animationReport(as)) if you remove delay. You have all covered in this answer...

Comment: @ikiK when i move the script to <head> it's worked.
but when i put the script to bottom of <body> even "report again" still result all "no animation".

Comment: maybe the script was not executed because the animation has already started before the "animationstart" event.

Comment: @BaoPham Just a crazy idea but keep this script in head? :) Jokes aside, this does answer question asked, what you asking now may be different one. Not sure myself about everything  whats going on in this answer, But your problem obliviously have something to do with DOM and document load, and considering what this scripts does this can be tricky to understand. And to say it out laud, i spent 2 hours on trying to make this simpler. I failed. I think this is good as it gets. Keep your script in head is my suggestion.

Comment: @BaoPham try to wrap all this into document.onreadystatechange  while keeping the script below body, but I don't think that will do what you want considering the content of script.

Comment: "ikiK" "cars10m" Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.